# regex - using "+ " quantifier consecutively

Tags: javascript, regex

Adding/removing the "+" doesn't change the output. But I don't get any errors either. what does "+" do here ?

```
/.{3}+/g
```

Comment: In js it's an error. In other, `+` acts as a possessive quantifier.

Comment: This is called `possessive quantifiers`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: It's very odd that you don't get any errors with the `+`. In what environment? Can you provide the complete program with its output, or series of console commands? Are you saying the `/.{3}+/` expression actually functioned to match some input?

Comment: No need of `{3}` here if you want one or more of any characters, you can simply use `/.+/g`. If you want to match `+` literal, escape it `/.{3}\+/g`

Comment: thank you,  i was using an environment other than javascript on regex101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex [debugger](https://regex101.com/)

It parsers the regex and describes it in detail

```
/.{3}+/g
    .{3}+ matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: {3}+ Exactly 3 times
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: When using regex101, make sure to select JavaScript. It will identify the `+` as an error in this case (following another quantifier).

Answer (score 2):

"+" is invalid here, maybe you mean

```
/(.{3})+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /.{3}+/g;
^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.{3}+/: Nothing to repeat at new RegExp (native)
```

This is what I get in nodejs (v.0.12.4)